# Extrair apk para colocar na playstore

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tendo problemas com Xml das minhas cores. Quando tento finalizar a extração, está dando erro, mas a aplicação corre no meu celular, ja fiz `clean and build` e está tudo bem, mas em contra partida, quando tento extrair para lançar na playstore, dão os seguintes erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Ficheiro Xml com as cores:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você possui apenas uma pasta value? ou existem mais para demais densidades? ( values-w820dp, por exemplo? ). Se tiver mais de uma verifique se todas possuem o arquivo color.xml

Comment: tenho apenas uma..

Comment: Poderia postar seu arquivo q contém as cores? Obrigado!

Comment: Ja esta adcionado

Answer (score 0):

Tente os seguintes passos:

1. Verifique se retirou o atributo debuggable da tag application no AndroidManifest;
2. Confira o versionCode e versionName no AndroidManifest;
3. Retire todos os arquivos que não estão sendo usado;
4. Teste novamente.

Comment: meu Manifest nao tem o atributo debuggable da tag aplication nem tem o versionCode e VersionName, o projecto corre inclusive ja testei em telemoveis diferentes...mais quanto tento fazer o export...